# How to make database entries stick to a User's account if those entries were created before the User account was

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, callback, user-accounts

I'm trying to think of the best way to allow users to create database objects without creating an account but then associating those objects with a user's account when they decide to sign up. I will describe an example application, how I would like it to behave, and the approaches I have come up with. I am looking for criticisms/enhancements to my approaches or a better approach purposed by one of you, my fellow programmers.

## Example Application

Let's say we have a Rails application called **Suggestion Box**. This application allows users to visit the site and enter a suggestion. A `Suggestion` requires a description and an email address. The user does not need to be logged in. Here are the models:

*app/models/suggestion.rb*

```
class Suggestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == DB Columns
  # id           :integer
  # user_id      :integer
  # description  :text
  # email        :string

  belongs_to :user

  validates :description, :email, :presence => true    
end
```

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecored::Base
  # == DB Columns
  # id           :integer
  # name         :string
  # email        :string

  has_many :suggestions

  validates :name, :email, :presence => true    
end
```

## Use Case

Frank comes to the Suggestion Box application and enters in a suggestion. The next day Frank enters in another. If we ask the Rails console for all of suggestions we will get this:

```
# rails console
Suggestion.all
=> [#<Suggestion id: 1, user_id: nil, email: "frank@example.com", description: "Don't worry">, 
#<Suggestion id: 2, user_id: nil, email: "frank@example.com", description: "Be happy">]
```

On the third day Frank decides to bite the bullet and sign up for an account. He then creates another suggestion. At this point if we ask the console for `User` objects we get Frank:

```
# rails console
User.all
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "Frank", email: "frank@example.com" >]
```

If we ask for Frank's suggestions we get all 3 suggestions:

```
# rails console
frank = User.last
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "Frank", email: "frank@example.com" >
frank.suggestions
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Suggestion id: 1, user_id: nil, email: "frank@example.com", description: "Don't worry">,
#<Suggestion id: 2, user_id: nil, email: "frank@example.com", description: "Be happy">,
#<Suggestion id: 3, user_id: nil, email: "frank@example.com", description: "Don't worry be happy now!">]
```

Now how do we make this connection between Frank and his past suggestions automatic?

## Approaches

#### #1 Cookies

When a non logged in user submits a session I could store an indicator in a cookie about the created suggestions. Then when they sign up I could use this info to find the suggestions and assign them to the user.

I don't really like this approach because it breaks down when the user accesses more than one device.

#### #2 After Create Callback

When a user signs up I could run an after create callback that would look like this:

*app/models.user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecored::Base
  ...

  after_create :assign_suggestions

  def assign_suggestions
    suggestions = Suggestion.where(:user_id => nil, :email => self.email)
    suggestions.each do |s|
      s.user = self
      s.save
    end 
  end   
end
```

I really like this approach but there is one major downside. If Frank creates a fourth suggestion when not logged in it will not be added to his user object. To fix this I could write a callback on the `Suggestion` class that could check for matching emails.

*app/models/suggestion.rb*

```
class Suggestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...  

  after_create :assign_users

  def assign_users
    if self.user.present?
      user = User.where(:email => self.email).first
      if user
        self.user = user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is pretty good but if Frank creates a suggestion with a different email address (which could happen, I have many) then the suggestion will not be connected to Frank's user object.

## Question

What  do you guys think of Approach #2? (good or bad) Is there another trick on top of this I could use to connect Frank to suggestions he makes with other email addresses? Can you think of a different approach that would work better than mine?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to solve two scenarios at once: assigning the user is you main question, and handling multiple email addresses to one account.

The `email address` field is duplicated in two models. Initially I would have suggested leave the email address in `User`, and create anonymous (no name) `User`s and then build from there. That would change your `Suggestion` create process since you would be associating to the `User` record immediately. Since you're trying to handle the multiple email question, I would suggest breaking the email address out into a separate model:

```
class EmailAddress << ActiveRecord::Base
  # == DB Columns
  # id           :integer
  # user_id      :integer
  # email        :string

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :suggestions
  validates :email, presence :true
end
```

change the other models accordingly:

```
class Suggestion << ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  belongs_to :email
end

class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_many :email
end
```

It would be your option to either create `User` immediately or defer it until they actually sign up for an account (I would defer).

As for the scenario of someone creating a suggestion when not signed up and having to make that association after the fact. This structure makes that easier BUT I would actually not allow that personally. I would inform the user something like `this email address is already registered, please sign in to submit your suggestion`. Assuming you want to make sure that people aren't falsely creating suggestions under other people's names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like your idea of putting the email into a separate model. `User` objects could then own `Suggestion` objects through the `Email` object. To prevent people from falsely entering Suggestions under another email I was going to confirm the suggestion  by sending an email to the submitter unless they are signed in.

Comment: Glad you like the suggestion. I would definitely send a confirm email for each un-registered suggestion. Though, once a user has an account it would be easier/more uniform to require login rather than continue to send confirmation emails. If you find the solution useful please remember to accept the solution.